# How to verify build args is set properly in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've got the following line in Dockerfile:

```
ARG COOL_ID
...
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/share/java/${COOL_ID}/app.jar"]
```

but when I run it there's an error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /usr/share/java//app.jar
```

and I can see that my `${COOL_ID}` argument was not formatted correctly.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can post your full `Dockerfile`, possible scope issue when using the `ARG` instruction, e.g. "An `ARG` declared before a `FROM` is outside of a build stage, so it can’t be used in any instruction after a `FROM`" ref. [Understand how ARG and FROM interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Comment: You have to use shell form for this `ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2` and `ENV` as you are running in shell (instead of `ARG`).

Comment: Something like this should work:  

`ARG COOL_ID`

`ENV ENTRY_POINT=/usr/share/java/${COOL_ID}/app.jar`
`ENTRYPOINT java -jar $ENTRY_POINT` (or `CMD java -jar $ENTRY_POINT`)

Answer (score 2):

It will not substitute the variable, as Docker treat `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` as a command so processing variables like shell will not work. Try to change the `CMD` to run it as a shell and then you will able to process variable the same as the shell.

Also, you can not use `ARG` in CMD to treat them as an environment variable, you just use them inside Dockerfile, to use them as an environment variable you must assign them to some `ENV`.

```
ARG COOL_ID
ENV COOL_ID=$COOL_ID
```

I will also suggest to verify and check `COOL_ID` in Docker build time, if not set then it should print the warning or error to the user, see below example if `ARG` not passed to builds params then it will print an error message to the user.

```
ARG COOL_ID
#see ARG is for build time 
RUN if [  -z $COOL_ID ];then \
  >&2 echo  "\n****************Warning!!!!*************\n"; \
  >&2 echo "COOL_ID seems empty!" ;\
  fi

ENV COOL_ID=$COOL_ID
# ENV is for run time
CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -jar /usr/share/java/${COOL_ID}/app.jar"]
```

Now build the docker with `--build-arg`

```
docker build --build-arg COOL_ID=myid -t myjava .
```

If you missed passing COOL_ID you will be notified.

[image]

Comment: One small addition you may want is to call `exit 1` after that, so that the build does not continue on without the missing build argument. Something like:

```>&2 echo "COOL_ID is not set!"; exit 1; \ ```